# Expo Android apk crashes when playing lottie animation

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I recently updated expo clients (both android and ios) of my phone and only the android version crashed after trying to play lottie animation  (using dangerzone). Animations work fine in ios and also it did work in android before i update the apk.
I dont get any error message when the app crash, i only get system message saying "app crashed". Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: No, but I opened an [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2007) on Github. (using images in the animation might be the problem in your case, this error is not about that)